# Texture based on height, how to unwrap properly?

Tags: uv

I am trying to wrap a texture around a rock with many edges, and want it to look like you can see layers of rock. I get pretty close to what I want when I unwrap using cylindrical projection, but the UVs are very distorted. As you can see on the picture, it is very impractical to work with that.
Any tips on how to approach this? Thanks[image]

Comment: What do you mean by distortion? Looking at it from a side probably is something you call undistorted - but then changing perspective has to "distort".

Comment: I meant on the left, the UVs are very stretched, overlapping etc. They are all in this thin vertical line. Impossible to use that in a game engine.

Comment: I don't see that at all. What I see is that UV is scaled to 0 on X axis, making the texture 1-dimensional (and so replaceable by a color ramp)

Comment: Did you try Projection From View?